# Node not part of list Exception after removing node?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, linked-list

Here is a simple version of my code.

```
While (node != null && QtyAvailable > 0)
{
    int OldQty = node.Value.NeedQty;
    If (OldQty > 0)
    {
       int usedQty = node.Value.AddQTY(QtyAvailable);
    }
    QtyAvailable -= (OldQty - node.Value.NeedQty);
    If (node.Value.NeedQty == 0)
    {
        MyList.Remove(node);
    }
    node = node.next;
}
```

Anyway, I have a LinkedList (doubly linked) with some basic data.
I update the nodes as needed and if a node is used and is not needed any more I delete the node. However, every once in a while I get an exception saying something like node is not part of list right after the Remove(node) command.

I am using VS2012 and I find it interesting that the highlighted line for the exception is the line after the remove command, something that I have seen for many exceptions in 2012 but not all.
This exception is extremely rare, but I think this error should not be possible and is a bug.
I am using VS2012 with the latest updates, making a Forms application with C#. Compiling for Debug X86 on a Win 7 64-bit machine. This error also occurs if I compile to X64. I use x86 so I can do debug-time editing if needed.

Comment: It may be because of the way node.next works. You are trying to get the next node using a node that does not exist anymore. 
Try to use another node variable and set the next node to that. Then remove the node then set the node to the next node using the variable.

Comment: I thought of that possibility and I have tried doing that which requires other checks to see if node.previous or node.next exit, but it can still happen with this.

Comment: Also, the error occurs once in possibly hundreds of thousands of removes so I don't think The node.next on a removed node it the problem.

Comment: I looked closer at my code, and in most places I first go to another node and then delete the node in question. So maybe you are right and that is the issue. I changed the rest of the code to do the same and I am testing. Will see if the error shows up again.

Comment: I hope that works for you.